# Universality of the Simplex Category

Tags: ct.category-theory

This is not a research level question, but I have not been able to find a satisfactory proof of functoriality of a certain map, and have posted this on several sites, with no luck. I wonder if anyone can give me a sensible proof.

Let $B$ be a strict monoidal category, and $\left \langle c,\mu ',\eta ' \right \rangle$ a monoid in $B$. Now suppose we consider the simplex category $\left \langle \triangle ,+,0 \right \rangle$, the monoid $\left \langle 1,\mu ,\eta \right \rangle$and define $F:\Delta \rightarrow B$ in the obvious way:

On objects take

$Fn=c^{n}$ (so that in particular $F0=\eta $ and $F1=c$.

On arrows, note that if $f:m\rightarrow n=$ then $f=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mu ^{m_{i}}$ with $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}m_{i}=m$ and $f(j)=i$ if $j\in m_{i}$, for all $0\leq j\leq m-1$, so it makes sense to set

$Ff=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\mu' )^{m_{i}}$

Now let $g:n\rightarrow k$ so that $g=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\mu ^{n_{i}}$, with $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}n_{i}=n$ and $g(j)=i$ if $j\in n_{i}$, for all $0\leq j\leq k-1$.

My problem is proving that $F$ is a functor. That is, that $F(g)F(f)=F(gf)$. This amounts to showing  that

$(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mu ^{m_{i}})(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\mu ^{n_{i}})$ composes in the same way as $(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\mu ') ^{m_{i}})(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(\mu ')^{n_{i}})$.

Let $k_{1},k_{2},\cdots, k_{n}$ be any set of $n$ integers. Then, we know that

$\mu ^{n}(\left ( \mu ^{k_{1}} \otimes \mu ^{k_{2}}\right )\otimes \cdots \mu ^{k_{n}})=\mu ^{k_{1}+k_{2}+\cdots +k_{n}}$.

I thought the proof wold be a trivial application of this but it doesn't seem so.

I have tried considering the product $Fgf$ written $Fgf:c^{m}\rightarrow c^{k}$, $Fgf=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(\mu ')^{m'_{i}}$, with $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}m'_{i}=m$ and $Fgf(j)=i$ if $j\in m'_{i}$, for all $0\leq j\leq k-1$. Then I need to show that

$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(\mu ')^{m'_{i}}=(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(\mu ') ^{m_{i}})(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(\mu ')^{n_{i}})$. But I have not been able to prove this, although there are interesting relations here using the definitions of the $m _{i},m' _{i}$ and $n _{i}$.

I do have $\mu ^{k}(\mu '^{m'_{0}}\otimes \cdots \otimes \mu '^{m'_{k-1}})=\mu ^{k}(\mu '^{m_{0}}\otimes \cdots \otimes \mu '^{m_{n-1}})(\mu '^{n_{0}}\otimes \cdots \otimes \mu '^{n_{k-1}})$ and so I tried induction on $k$, but to no avail.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Note: The associative law follows from setting $\mu _{e}=\eta, \mu _{c}= 1_{c}, \mu _{c\otimes c}=\mu $ and thereafter $\mu _{u_{c}\otimes v_{c}}=\mu(\mu _{u_{c}}\otimes \mu _{v_{c}})$ Then, the multiplication is, using the notation for powers of $c$, $\mu ^{0}= \eta $, $\mu ^{1}=1_{c}$, $\mu ^{2}=\mu $, and thereafter, $\mu ^{n+1}=\mu \left ( \mu ^{n} \otimes 1\right )$. From this you get the result in a strict monoidal category.

Comment: Observe that the Simplicial category is definible as a free category with objects the natural numers, and formal maps the usal simbols $\delta_i$ and $\sigma_i$... quotient the usual canonical simplicial relations.

you can find in as in Prop.2 p.178 of "CAtegories for the WOrking Mathematics" S. McLane (2 ed).

Comment: If you are presenting the simplex category in a standard way as generated from faces $\delta_i^n: n \to n+1$ and degeneracies $\sigma_i^n: n+1 \to n$, subject to the simplicial identities, then all you have to do is check that the interpretation of the simplicial identities hold in the strict monoidal category $B$. Have you tried that? It seems to me you might be making things more complicated than you have to (and also you seem to be ignoring degeneracy maps).

Comment: @ToddTrimble: Yes, I know that once $\Delta $ is presented in this way, the it's easy to show $F$ is a functor. But Maclane defines $F$ before doing so, and claims it is a functor. So, I feel it's cheating to use the standard presentation in my proof. Thanks for your time on this non-research topic.

Comment: Okay, I'd have to track down my copy of Mac Lane then to see what he does exactly, before preparing an answer (which I might post here or at Math.SE). You probably should mention in your post that it is Mac Lane's treatment that you are trying to follow. My vague memory is that he deduces the standard presentation by putting maps between ordinals in a normal form, but again I'd need to check.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: Maclane first observes that $\left \langle \Delta, +,0 \right \rangle$ is a monoidal category and that $\left \langle 1, \mu ,\eta \right \rangle$ is a monoid in $\Delta $ where $\mu :2\rightarrow 1$ and $\eta :0\rightarrow 1$. So $f:n\rightarrow m$ is then expressed in terms of $\mu $ and $\eta $ only. It is not until after he sketches the proof that $F$ is a unique morphism of categories that he introduces the $\delta _{i}$ and $\sigma _{i}$.